# Did this part come from my bicycle?

Tags: road-bike, shimano, maintenance, safety, parts

I was working on my bicycle, a 2021 Domane SL5, and laid it on the ground. When I picked it up, I saw a small metal ring on the ground underneath. I don’t know for certain if the metal piece came off the bike, but what do you think? Is this a part from the bike?

I was installing a DuoTrap sensor. I thought maybe it came from the rubber grommet or part of the installation kit for the sensor but I haven’t been able to confirm; installing the sensor seemed to be fine so I’m not sure if it’s a needed part.

[image: the top of it]
[image: the flat of it]

Comment: Looks too clean to be off of my bike

Comment: FYI, DuoTrap is a speed/cadence sensor that can be integrated into Trek frames. I'm not sure how the arrangement works, but could this metal item have come from the door that you plug the DuoTrap sensor into?

Comment: @WeiwenNg it might have come from the duo-trap rubber thing. The instructions mention a 2mm grommet. I wonder if the sensor is even installed correctly?

Comment: Looks like a cable pulley to me, or something to guide a cable round a bend. I’m not sure how it would have been mounted to a bike though.

Comment: Hard to tell without a scale, but it looks like the fastening that joins a disc rotor to its spider.

Comment: I agree, it does look like a rivet from a floating rotor design

Comment: Can you say more about it? @bertie

Comment: See e.g. https://www.wiggle.co.uk/lifeline-floating-disc-rotor-160mm the parts between the black alloy spider and the silver steel friction surface.But that's just a guess - I can't tell from your picture how big it is.

Comment: I was working on my bike.  A small part rolled into the drain pipe.  Now I know where it went.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check this video: Youtube, "Installing a Bontrager Duotrap S Sensor on a Trek Domane":

At 1:32, the guy who's installing the Duotrap holds a rubber bushing/gasket/seal-thingey and with the thumb and forefinger of his right hand he's holding onto the front outer part of that seal where you can see a metal spacer that probably makes the Duotrap sit at the correct distance from the frame?

BR
Magnus

Comment: Whoa, that will probably earn me a badge for "Thread revival of 2023"...

Comment: Magnus - maybe not a badge but a bounty for answering an otherwise unanswered and difficult question.   Keep it up !